# Trigonometric equation $\cos\left(3x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\sin(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having trouble understanding these types of equations.

$$\cos\left(3x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\sin(x)$$

Options are given below:

a) $x = \dfrac{3k\pi}{2} + \dfrac{3\pi}{16}$ and $x= 2k\pi- \dfrac{\pi}{8}$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

b) $x= \dfrac{\pi}{2} + \dfrac{3\pi}{16}$ and $x= k\pi- \dfrac{\pi}{4}$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

c) $x= \dfrac{k\pi}{2} + \dfrac{3\pi}{16}$ and $x= k\pi- \dfrac{\pi}{8}$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

d) $x= \dfrac{k\pi}{2} - \dfrac{3\pi}{16}$ and $x= k\pi+ \dfrac{\pi}{8}$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

I would really like to have some explanations how to deal with this problems.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos\left(3x - \frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \sin x$$
Since $\sin x = \cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - x\right)$, we obtain
$$\cos\left(3x - \frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right)$$
Now, consider the diagram below.

[image: symmetry_diagram_for_sine_and_cosine]

Two angles have the same cosine if the $x$-coordinates of the points where the terminal sides of the angle intersect the unit circle are equal.  By symmetry, $\cos\theta = \cos\varphi$ if $\theta = \pm \varphi$.  Since any angle coterminal with these angles will have the same cosine, we obtain the general solution $\cos\theta = \cos\varphi$ if 
$$\theta = \pm \varphi + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
To solve the problem above, let 
$$\theta = 3x - \frac{\pi}{4}$$
and 
$$\varphi = \frac{\pi}{2} - x$$